# How can i input data from txt file and input system in array form with FileInputStream?

Tags: java

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class HW104 {
    public static void inputData(String filename) {
        int[] a = new int[3];
        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
            int i = input.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                System.out.println((char) i);
                i = input.read();
            }

            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputData("arabaa.txt");
    }
}
```

How can i input data from txt file and input system in array form with FileInputStream? I need to get datas in array form.

Comment: If it's truly a text file, then use a `Reader` implementation to read the characters. Then parse the characters into whatever data you need as appropriate.

Comment: Try looking at [Read a file using FileInputStream in Java](https://www.techiedelight.com/how-to-read-a-file-using-fileinputstream-in-java/).